# Не удаётся создать подключение к OpenVPN на Raspberry Pi

Tags: openvpn, raspberry-pi

Установил на Raspberry Pi PiVPN согласно данному [ресурсу](http://www.pivpn.io/). Подключение настроил по протоколу tcp. Перенаправление портов на маршрутизаторе настроил. Трафик на Raspberry Pi проходит - проверено другими сервисами. Тем не менее при попытке подключиться через openvpn клиент получаю следующее:

```
Sun Jan 07 16:58:34 2018 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Sun Jan 07 16:58:34 2018 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
```

Как возможно это устранить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это зависит от конфигурации самого сервера. В конфиге OpenVPN можно задать  `proto udp` или `proto tcp`. Если сервер Ваш - перенастройте. Одновременно два протокола использовать нельзя, для этого нужно запускать два экземпляра `openvpn` с разными конфигами. Лично я использую протокол TCP, потому что между моим OpenVPN сервером и клиентом теряются пакеты и при использовании UDP бывает что на некоторое время пропадает соединение, а в случае TCP все будет корректироваться максимально быстро.

Answer (score 0):

Ну нашёл костыль своеобразный. Проблема была в файле сертификате, который генерировал сервер. Внутри самого файла был указан способ подключения - udp. Скорректировал его на tcp и соединение начало проходить. НО в той же [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVPN) рекомендуют всё же использоваться UDP. А вот через UDP вылезает тажа самая ошибка.